# Go template HTMLEscape json data and it show "&#34;" issue

Tags: json, go, html-escape-characters, html-escape

i try to put json data to web, i use `json.Marshal` to create json data.

Flowing picture is `fmt.Println(string(jsonOut))` result

[image]

i use `template.HTMLEscape(w, []byte(jsonOut))` to show in web, it will show like following picture.

[image]

the `"` become `&#34`.

why it will show `&#34` and how can i do for show `"`?

Comment: try not call `template.HTMLEscape`

Comment: @zzn if i don't call `template.HTMLEscape` what should i call to show json data in web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template.HTMLEscape` will escape special character.

use following code can post json data to web

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
w.Write(jsonOut)
```

reference 
https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/golang-response-snippets#json

Answer (score 2):

If you just want show json in the http response

```
w.Write(jsonOut)
```

If you want to show json in html

```
t, _ := template.New("foo").Parse(`<head></head><body>{{$.data}}</body>`)   
_ = t.Execute(w, map[string]string{
    "data": string(jsonOut),
})
```